# How to spread objects along axis?

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

I have a set of closely positioned objects. I want to make animation of spreading them along one axis with preferably equal gaps. I don't want to use parenting because i want to be able to rotate them freely around they centers later.

What is the simplest way to do this. Can it be achieved with animation nodes plugin or do i have to use only Blender animation curves and make all movements manually?

The following animation shows what i want to achieve with small number of objects.

[image: moving parts]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two keyframes will suffice, if the centers of the objects are already spread out in the correct order.

1. Check the [manipulate center points](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/manipulate_center_points.html#manipulate-center-points) button.
   [image: manipulate center points]
2. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> select the objects.
3. Press <kbd>I</kbd> and choose *Location* to keyframe the location.
4. Move the cursor in the timeline to the second position. I have the dopesheet open to see the created keyframes.
5. Press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale the objects. Because of the *Manipulate Center Points only* button, the objects will only be moved, but not scaled. You can constrain the movent to a specific axis, by pressing <kbd>S</kbd>><kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>><kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>S</kbd>><kbd>Z</kbd>.
6. Repeat *3* to insert a second keyframe.

[image]

Comment: I would like to obtain gaps between objects of the same size. But this method does not guarantee this. How do I align objects after scalling?

Comment: 2,8x See Locations in transform tool settings.

Comment: Maybe add another answer? This seems to be the missing piece for the quesiton.

Answer (score 1):

When you need to rotate them as you wrote, use **clear parent and keep transform**. Unparented objects are your next keyframe.